# Problems transferring files to a smartphone

Tags: android

This morning I was copying some files from my computer (running Ubuntu 16.10) to my Galaxy S5 (Running Android 6.x). 6 of the files threw an error message which read:

```
    libmtp: could not send object info
```

Another file threw the error message:

```
    libmtp: file not found
```

As these were only 7 files out of nearly 800, it did not suggest a problem with libmtp being corrupt, so what was the issue?

Comment: Hello DarkStrar, as you already provide an answer to your question, please answer your own question so that the question conforms to the askubuntu format. Otherwise it will be deleted and this would be a pitty.

Answer (score 1):

As I examined each of the files closely, I discovered a commonality among 6 them:  **They all had a colon in the file name!** (I did not name them - somebody else did). As soon as I re-named the files, removing the colon, the files were transferred without further problems.

But what of the seventh file that caused my system to throw the 'file not found' error?  I double-checked to confirm the file was present in its folder, and it was. As I examined the file name closely, I immediately saw the problem:  **A space had been included in the file name** (how I was able to receive the file is a mystery for the time being).  Again, I renamed the file by removing the space and the transfer went through instantly.

**I am posting this to serve as a cautionary tale** to other users who may have trouble transferring a file, especially to their smart phones, to ***ALWAYS*** confirm that there are ***NO*** illegal characters in the file's name ***FIRST*** before looking for more exotic causes for your problem.  Or, as we used to be reminded when I was in college: ***When you hear hoof beats, think horses, not zebras!***

I hope some people find this to be beneficial.

Cheers!